# ASP.NET 1.1 application failed connecting after migrating from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, odbc, sql-server-2000, dsn

We have an ASP.NET 1.1 application installed on server A and SQL Server 2000 on server B. We want to migrate our database from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008.

The issue is we don't have the code for ASP application as it was developed by some third party development company which does not exist any more. So the only thing we are left with is pre-compiled code and DLL's. I disassembled the DLL files with PE explorer to figure out that the ADODB connection is made using DSN's. We upgraded SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 on server B and installed SQL Server native client driver in server A so that our application can use that ODBC driver to connect to SQL Server 2008. I reconfigured DSN with the new ODBC driver and the ASP application still does not work. It is not able to connect to database.

Additional Information: we have an application pool for the ASP.NET application in IIS and I restarted the COM component but no luck. I try to test the database connection using a simple test.asp file from server A using the following code and it connects.

```
dim ObjConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

' DSN 
ObjConn.Open("dsn=xxx;uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx")

Dim ObjRS = ObjConn.Execute(" xxx 'xxx','xxx','xxx',0,null,null ")
```

My question is whether ASP.NET 1.1 application will work with SQL Server 2008 or is it impossible. As far as i know if the application is using DSN's to connect to database and if we reconfigure it with right ODBC driver that should not be a problem.

Comment: You don't say anything about the error received. This could be very helpful

Comment: The application shows custom error message and does not display the actual exception generated. Sadly i dont have the code for ASP application.

Comment: Look at the EventViewer on the server that is running the ASP.net application. It might capture error messages.

Comment: Have you tried using RedGate's Reflector to debug the assemblies? That might allow you to see how it is really failing.

Comment: I already checked event viewer on both the servers and nothing logged  when i try to access the application. I am trying to install SQL 2008 on the same server where application is and check if the application works and see if there is an issue of SQL 2008 configuration as it is installed on a remote server right now.

Comment: Can i use redgate reflector to debug assemblies of an active application running on IIS?

Comment: I tried to debug it with .net reflector. It gives me an error not a .net module. May be the assembly was obfuscated and meta data was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use ASP.net 1.1 with SQL Server 2008.

Have you checked to see if the permissions have changed between the original server and the new server?

Comment: Are you talking about the account permissions. The permissions are same as of the old server. Also the SQL upgrade imports all the logins and configuration to new server right. I checked out the tcp/ip and named pipes are enabled on both the servers also the surface configuration for sql 2008 remote connections was enabled.

Comment: Yep, that is one of the items that could be preventing the web app from talking to the database.

Comment: I double checked the account permission and i am able to connect to database with the same account from different server using a SQL client. I even checked the application pool identity and it is using Network Service account so i added that credential in SQL 2008 but still no luck.